# How to get a list of immutable identifier (digest) from a Docker image?

Tags: docker, digest, dockerhub

I have a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/reynierpm/docker-lamp) in dockerhub and this has been built several times because I need to update the PHP version to the newest. I need to use a previous version of that image and I think the way to go is by using the immutable identifier aka digest.

[Here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier) is the documentation in how to pull a given image by it's digest but I can't find a way to get all the digest from that image.

If you double click on a given build you obtain certain information like a build code, for example: `berpxpunhmqe7bqh6lce5ub` but I don't think that is such digest.

How do I find that digest for a given build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a tag/identifier for the previous version and/or have a version in you local image cache, finding the digest to use with *pull by digest* can be done with a `docker image inspect` as follows:

```
$ docker image inspect --format "{{.RepoDigests}}" alpine:3.6
[alpine@sha256:b40e202395eaec699f2d0c5e01e6d6cb8e6b57d77c0e0221600cf0b5940cf3ab]
```

In this example I'm looking at the **3.6** tag of the **alpine** image, and the response is a string I can use with commands like `docker pull`:

```
$ docker pull alpine@sha256:b40e202395eaec699f2d0c5e01e6d6cb8e6b57d77c0e0221600cf0b5940cf3ab
sha256:b40e202395eaec699f2d0c5e01e6d6cb8e6b57d77c0e0221600cf0b5940cf3ab: Pulling from library/alpine
Digest: sha256:b40e202395eaec699f2d0c5e01e6d6cb8e6b57d77c0e0221600cf0b5940cf3ab
Status: Image is up to date for alpine@sha256:b40e202395eaec699f2d0c5e01e6d6cb8e6b57d77c0e0221600cf0b5940cf3ab
```

The potential problem with your specific image is that it looks like the `latest` tag has been used for all your builds, so unless you have a local cache of an older image, it may be quite difficult to find the older *sha256* digest references to prior builds.

There are a few possible ways to find the digest of a prior image if local cached information hasn't been deleted via `docker system prune` or other cleanup utilities:

1. `docker images -a | grep <image name>` can be used to display all images, including those which have been untagged. A below example shows an updated **ubuntu:latest** where I still have access to the older image. Using that ID (which is not a digest), I can use the same `docker image inspect --format '{{.RepoDigests}}' <image ID>` to retrieve the actual digest of an older "build" of ubuntu.
2. If I had a container that is running or exited using a prior version of the image, I could find the digest of that image by first inspecting the container and finding the **image ID**, and then inspecting that **image ID** as above and retrieving the older image's digest. In this somewhat contrived example I have an exited container, *1edd..*, which I inspect to find the **image ID**, which happens to still be validly tagged, but using it's *id* I can then use `image inspect` to get the digest, even if it is no longer tagged in my image cache.

**Example 1:**

```
$ docker images -a | grep ubuntu
ubuntu       latest      747cb2d60bbe   3 weeks ago    122MB`
ubuntu       <none>      ebcd9d4fca80   5 months ago   118MB
$ docker image inspect --format '{{.RepoDigests}}' ebcd9
 [ubuntu@sha256:382452f82a8bbd34443b2c727650af46aced0f94a44463c62a9848133ecb1aa8]
```

**Example 2:**

```
$ docker ps -aq
1edd14b528db
$ docker container inspect 1edd | grep Image
    "Image": "sha256:76da55c8019d7a47c347c0dceb7a6591144d232a7dd616242a367b8bed18ecbc",
        "Image": "alpine:3.6",
$ docker image inspect --format '{{.RepoDigests}}' 76da55
[alpine@sha256:f006ecbb824d87947d0b51ab8488634bf69fe4094959d935c0c103f4820a417d]
```

Comment: That is exactly my issue I have been using the same tag each time I build the image and that becomes a problem. If I'd use a version each time I won't even need to search for the digest since the tag would be enough but sadly I didn't make this properly and now I have such issue. Let's wait on other answer if any otherwise I will accept yours.

Comment: I added a few examples of finding a digest that may still be in the image cache from a container that used it or simply by listing all untagged images in your local cache. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That helps me to find the digest of the current image I am using at work (the one I wanted to find) so I will test later today at home and see if that digest works. Thanks I have accepted your answer